# Como obtener el IMEI al instalar por primera vez la aplicación en el móvil

Tags: android

Estoy intentando obtener el imei al instalar por primera vez en android 8.0 pero me da un error de permisos, se los estoy dando pero aun así me da error

---

Acá comparto el código con el cual lo estoy intentando hacer, de ante mano agradezco por su ayuda.

Creación de arreglo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego en el Oncreate
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para la verificación he creado el siguiente método:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto al instalar la aplicación por primera vez en el dispositivo levanta los diálogos que el usuario debera aceptar.

Comment: Hola David, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Pásate por el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y ganar tu primera medalla. Un saludo.

Comment: Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve], sería ideal que compartieras el código en modo texto en lugar de como imágenes. En general es más fácil de leer y facilita las pruebas y que se te pueda ayudar.

Comment: Hola Alvaro, muchas gracias por tus sugerencias, trabajare para mejorar en esa área, soy nuevo en esto y me estoy adaptando.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Nota: Necesita permisos de tiempo de ejecución

Agregué el permiso READ_PHONE_STATE dentro del archivo AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

en MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback{
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE = 999;
    private TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager;
    String IMEI

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_actividad_dos);

        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
        } else {
            getDeviceImei();
        }
    }

    private void getDeviceImei() {
        mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        IMEI = mTelephonyManager.getDeviceId();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            getDeviceImei();
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Grs Chml, fue de mucha ayuda

Comment: Saludos! solo marcala como una respuesta util y le sirva a los demas